# Recipes in Settings.JSON for Latex Workshop extension not showing

Tags: vscode

I tried to edit/add some recipes to the Latex Workshop extension of VSCode. However, when I open settings.json, the thing that appears is this:

```
{
    "clangd.path": "/home/guillermh/.config/Code - OSS/User/globalStorage/llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd/install/11.0.0/clangd_11.0.0/bin/clangd",
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
    "latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "never",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai"
}
```

which is very different from the expected format shown in several answers in all the web and in the latexworkshop documentation, which is the following:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
  {
    "name": "latexmk ",
    "tools": [
      "latexmk"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex`×2",
    "tools": [
      "pdflatex",
      "bibtex",
      "pdflatex",
      "pdflatex"
    ]
  }
]
```

Maybe this is not a Latex Workshop problem, the settings files appear to be very different from what I expected :/

What could be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings.json start typing `latex-workshop.latex.recipes` on a new line inside the settings and then use auto-completion to insert the missing recipes.

This is due to how [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) work in VSCode and specifically that the default settings are not shown by default.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't even try this haha